# Наследование с целью использования Private конструктора

Tags: c++, наследование

Привет! Я питонист, но из приличия решил заботать с++.
**Задание:** есть класс `Foo` с `private` конструктором. Есть функция `foo_says` которая использует `public` метод класса `Foo`. Надо написать  функцию `get_foo`, благодаря которой будет компилиться:

```
foo_says(get_foo("Hello!"));
```

Код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstddef> // size_t
#include <cstring> // strlen, strcpy
using namespace std;



struct Foo {
    void say() const { std::cout << "Foo says: " << msg << "\n"; }
protected:
     Foo(const char *msg) : msg(msg) { }
private:
     const char *msg;
};

struct Fo : Foo {
    Fo(const char* msg) : Foo(msg) { }
};

void foo_says(const Foo &foo) {
    foo.say(); }

const Foo& get_foo(const char *msg) {
    const Fo F(msg);
    const Foo& f = F;
    return f;;
}

int main()
{
    foo_says(get_foo("Hello!"));

    return 0;
}
```

**Решение и проблема:** Так как задание из раздела "Наследование классов", то я наследовал `Fo`, который создаст объект, а потом его можно будет привести(срезкой) к объекту `Foo`. Но вместо строки Hello я получаю ��.��. Подозреваю, что после выхода из какой то функции удаляется указатель на Hello, потому что "Foo says" выводится исправно. Тогда где это происходит - понять не могу?

Comment: Учебное задание противоречит правилам стековерфлоу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Начнем с того, что у вас же задано

> класс `Foo` с `private` конструктором

а вы делаете `protected`. Чтобы достучаться до `private` конструктора, нужен только друг. Так что если позарез нужно наследование, то объявите наследник другом:

```
class Fo;
class Foo
{
    Foo(const char *msg) : msg(msg) { }
public:
    void say() const { std::cout << "Foo says: " << msg << "\n"; }
private:
    string msg;
    friend class Fo;
};
class Fo : public Foo {
public:
    Fo(const char* msg) : Foo(msg) { }
};
```

Что касается функции `get_foo`, то в ней можно выкрутиться ([@Majestio](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/225982/majestio) рассказал вам, в чем в ней неприятности), либо возвращая указатель

```
const Foo* get_foo(const char *msg)
{
    return new Fo(msg);
}
```

либо ссылку на статический объект:

```
const Foo& get_foo(const char *msg)
{
    static Fo(msg);
    return Fo;
}
```

Минус второго решения очевиден - объект один, и вы не сможете создать второй. Минус первого - в возврате указателя, который надо хранить и не забыть потом удалить.

Главный проектный минус - что вы хотите возвращать ссылку на `Foo`, которая фактически является ссылкой на `Fo`.

Лично я бы решал задачу без наследования, ибо в условии о нем ни слова, а для доступа к `private` конструктору все равно нужна дружба:

```
class Foo
{
    Foo(const char *msg) : msg(msg) { }
public:
    void say() const { std::cout << "Foo says: " << msg << "\n"; }
private:
    string msg;
    friend Foo get_foo(const char *msg);
};

void foo_says(const Foo &foo)
{
    foo.say();
}

Foo get_foo(const char *msg)
{
    return Foo(msg);
}

int main()
{
    foo_says(get_foo("Hello!"));
}
```

Кстати, обратите внимание на то, что член `msg` я сделал `string` - сейчас это не принципиально, но вдруг вы еще как-то захотите использовать этот класс, и будете передавать в конструктор не литерал...

Answer (score 2):

```
const Foo& get_foo(const char *msg) {
  const Fo F(msg);
  const Foo& f = F;
  return f;;
}
```

Вот тут вы возвращаете ссылку на объект локальной видимости. Это ведет к состоянию "неопределенного поведения" (undefined behavior). Пока это не решено - дальше "копать" смысла нет.

Comment: я также пробовал передавать сам объект, чтобы он копировался, но в таком случае, я не получаю ВООБЩЕ никакого вывода

Comment: + я точно знаю, что типа этой функции должен быть `const Foo&` => должна быть возвращена именно ссылка. Как в таком случае следует поступить??

Comment: Ссылаться на заведомо существующую сущность. Например, на поле объекта класса. Пока объект есть - есть и его поле. Не важно что там, важно что оно есть - и на него можно ссылаться. Второй вариант - создавать объект в куче (heap).

Comment: Очевидно авторы задания хотели возврата *this